# FirebaseUI auth with facebook error

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Error received:

> Error logging in with Facebook. SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1675030 [message]: ‎Error performing query.‎ [extra]: Errors while executing operation "ProxyAuthAppLoginStartQuery": At Query.proxy_auth_app_login_start: Field implementation threw an exception. Check your server logs for more information.

followed the answers around google and stack. doesnt work.
just to be sure: App id is correct & i am trying to log in with authorized user: 
[image]

Help :)

Comment: Have you configured your OAuth redirect URI?  From https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login, "make sure your OAuth redirect URI (e.g. my-app-12345.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler) is listed as one of your OAuth redirect URIs in your Facebook app's settings page on the Facebook for Developers site in the Product Settings > Facebook Login config.""

Comment: already been done. even though, it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

App under *Deployment* mode in Facebook

1. Select your App on Facebook Developer [Here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps).
2. Go to App Review > Make "Your App Name" application public -> Yes.

Hope this may Help you

Comment: hey, i dont want it to go public.
and i'm pretty sure it is possible connect to it threw FB while its in develop mode...

Answer (score 0):

This might works for you because Firebase UI was specifying the android:value,

```
<application
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Base">

<meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    tools:replace="android:value"
    android:value="@string/facebook_app_id" />
```